# How do you get the name of a calling module as a string using inspect in Python (I keep getting a module object)

Tags: python, module, inspect

I'm trying to get the name of a calling module by using inspect. When I return what should be the module string, I get this:

```
<module 'mymod.wrapper' from '/usr/local/lib/python2
```

I've looked at the [docs](http://docs.python.org/library/inspect.html) and couldn't see anything about what the reason for this may be (I'm tired, so I may have missed it).

Here is the class

```
import inspect


class Wrapper():


    def getView(self, view, database=False):

        module = self._getDatabase()
        print(module)

    def _getDatabase(self):

        # Get calling module
        frm = inspect.stack()[1]
        modWhole = str(inspect.getmodule(frm[0]))
        modSplit = modWhole.split('.')
        mod = modSplit[0] + '.' + modSplit[1]
        return mod
```

Also, any advice on how to reconize and prevent this problem in the future is much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`inspect.getmodule()` returns the module object itself, not its name.

Try replacing

```
str(inspect.getmodule(frm[0]))
```

with

```
inspect.getmodule(frm[0]).__name__
```

Also, bear in mind that `inspect.getmodule()` can return `None`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `__name__` attribute:

```
>>> import xml
>>> xml.__name__
'xml'
>>> m = __import__('xml')
<module 'xml' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/xml/__init__.pyc'>
>>> m.__name__
'xml'
```